# Multiple concurrent rails servers with binding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, binding, lan

I have a rails staging server available to my LAN as follows:

```
rails server --binding=0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

I would now like to open up a second, concurrent rails server to my LAN as follows:

```
rails server --binding=0.0.0.0 -p 3001
```

Unfortunatly, I am getting this error message:

```
...
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3001
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
A server is already running. ...
```

The error only exists if I use `--binding=0.0.0.0` on both servers, which is necessary if I want it to be accessible to my LAN.

How can I open up multiple rails servers on the same machine to the LAN, not just `localhost`?

EDIT:

After trying Vasfed's solution, e.g.

```
rails server --binding=0.0.0.0 -p 3000 --pid=tmp/pids/server0.pid
rails server --binding=0.0.0.0 -p 3001 --pid=tmp/pids/server1.pid
```

the problem persists, but this time I have more information. It seems related to a port 9292 being opened...

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3001
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Private Caller
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9292
Exiting
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:269:in `initialize': Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 9292 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

Comment: please post your `config/puma.rb`

Comment: @Vasfed Ah, yes. config/puma.rb was missing. I added ```port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3001 }``` and that seems to halve solved the issue with 9292. Still not sure why exactly this only happens if I bind the rails server to 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 4):

Rails checks if a pid file is already present. To run two copies of single app, you should alter pids too:

```
rails server --binding=0.0.0.0 -p 3000 --pid=tmp/pids/server1.pid
rails server --binding=0.0.0.0 -p 3001 --pid=tmp/pids/server2.pid
```

Comment: Tried this, problem persists, but with more info. See edit.